# When can I activate EDI?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Title was left intentionally vague.  Spoilers ahead.

> So one of the first things to happen after leaving Earth is to recover a Cerberus infiltration unit. From the wiki, I know that EDI can inhabit the mech and become a squad member.

When exactly does this happen?

Comment: I believe this happens after Palavan's moon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early on in the game just before you leave Palaven and are asked to investigate the Normandy's strange behaviour.